# How to pass context to nested serializers in Marshmallow?

Tags: python, marshalling, marshmallow

From their nested [example](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#nesting-serializers):

```
class BlogSerializer(Serializer):
    title = fields.String()
    author = fields.Nested(UserSerializer)

# This is different! I'm passing in a context
serialized = BlogSerializer(blog, context={'test': 1})
```

The `UserSerializer` doesn't seem to get the context when serializing the blog.
How do I pass the context down to the nested serializers?

Comment: At the moment I have to serialise the nested attribute in a method. Is this a good solution?

Comment: This is how I would handle it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027452/5698202 is the way to go in case you can't pass context to the OuterSchema and/or need to set when control is within the OuterSchema.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of [marshmallow 1.0.0-a](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html#changelog), nested field's `Function` and `Method` fields inherit context from their parent.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pprint

class InnerSchema(Schema):
    value = fields.Function(lambda val, ctx: 'foo' in ctx['from_outer'])

class OuterSchema(Schema):
    inner = fields.Nested(InnerSchema)

schema = OuterSchema(context={'from_outer': 'foo'})
obj = {'inner': {}}
result = schema.dump(obj)
pprint(result.data)  # {"inner": {"value": true}}
```