# Marshmallow serialize nested with parent field

Tags: flask, marshmallow

Sorry if this has been asked before, I could not actually find a solution or similar question (maybe using the wrong words).

I'm updating an existing Flask API that receives data from a client we don't control (can't change the JSON data format), using marshmallow and peewee.

The data format comes this way:

```
{
    "site_id": "0102931",
    "update_date": "2018/02/11-09:33:23",
    "updated_by": "chan1",
    "crc": "a82131cf232ff120aaf00001293f",
    "data": [{"num": 1,
              "id": "09213/12312/1",
              "chain": "chain2",
              "operator": "0000122",
              "op_name": "Fred",
              "oid": "12092109300293"
             },
             {"num": 2,
              "id": "09213/12312/2",
              "chain": "chain1",
              "operator": "0000021",
              "op_name": "Melissa",
              "oid": "8883390393"
             }]           
}
```

We are not interested about anything in the main block, but the site_id,   which *must* be copied into each of the objects in the list when deserializing to create the models and store the data.

This is the model in peeewee:

```
class production_item(db.Model):
   site_id = TextField(null=False)
   id_prod = TextField(null=False)
   num = SmallIntegerField(null=False)
   chain = TextField(null=False)
   operator = TextField(null=False)
   operator_name = TextField(null=True)
   order_id = TextField(null=False)
```

And this is the marshamallow schema:

```
class prodItemSchema(Schema):
    num=String(required=True)
    id=String(required=True)
    chain=String(required=True)
    operator=String(required=True)
    op_name=String(required=False, allow_none=True)
    oid=String(required=False, allow_none=True)
```

I can't find a way to pass the site-id from the main structure with load() method and pre-load / post-load decorators for the prodItemSchema, so the model can't be created. Also, I'd like for marshmallow to validate the whole structure for me, not doing in two parts between the resource and the schema, as they are doing in the code right now.

But can't find a way in the documentation to make something like this, is that possible?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this with only one schema.You probably need two schemas, one for the main object and one for 'data' and do what you need in pre or post load hooks inside the schema for the main object.

Comment: I tried the nested schema, but could not find a way to gather the site_id value from the parent schema, so I ended up with an alternative way. I'll auto answer my own question with the code, it might be a better way, but this one works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In marshmallow it's possible to pass values from a parent scheme to its children before serialization by using the [pre_dump](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.decorators.pre_dump) decorator on the parent scheme to set the [context](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#schema). Once the context is set, a [function field](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Function) can be used to obtain the value from the parent.

```py
class Parent(Schema):
    id = fields.String(required=True)
    data = fields.Nested('Child', many=True)

    @pre_dump
    def set_context(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self.context['site_id'] = parent['id']
        return data

class Child(Schema):
    site_id = fields.Function(inherit_from_parent)

def inherit_from_parent(child, context):
    child['site_id'] = context['site_id']
    return child
```

Comment: oh, cool one, I didn't know you could use the context in such a way!